# Finding the frequency of words length n in a text file (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to find the number of words in a text file with corresponding lengths but were not allowed to import anything. 
Im not sure how to approach this problem after setting up the for loop.
I tried this way but it prints out not in an ordered way and i dont really know how to append it the way that they want it to be formatted (in the form of a dictionary so like {1: 1482, 2:2042 ...} that is what im not sure how to do.) Thanks

```
def dictify(book_name):
    infile = open(book_name,'r')
    text = infile.read()
    infile.close()
    words = text.split()
    lengths = dict()
    for word in words:
        length = len(word)
        if length not in lengths:
            lengths[length] = 0
        lengths[length] += 1
    for length, counter in lengths.items():
        print (length, counter)
```

Comment: Welcome @anonymous, please post what you have tried. SO is not an assignment solving service

Comment: `dictify = lambda book_name: Counter([len(i) for i in open(book_name).read().split())`

Comment: @XeroSmith Sorry i didnt post it, this is what ive tried to do but its not formatted in the way that i want it to be in a sense because for this i used a counter but i cant seem to modify it.

Comment: What is the _"way they want it to be formatted"_ ?

Comment: @BurhanKhalid in the form of a dictionary so like {1: 1482, 2:2042 ...} that is what im not sure how to do.

Comment: Did you try `print(lengths)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

code:

```
def dictify(book_name):
  infile = open(book_name,'r')
  text = infile.read()
  infile.close()
  words = text.split()
  lengths = {}
  for word in words:
      length = len(word)
      if length not in lengths:
          lengths[length] = 1
      else:
          lengths[length] += 1
  sd = sorted(lengths.items())
  for k,v in sd:
      print (k, v)
```

Try this code.
Do tell if it worked.